# Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR Look-Ahead and Look-Behind

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I am trying to write a regular expression which fetches minimum and maximum of width and length from the given text.
Eg. I have few sample texts as below.

```
1. S-BARE-w<=1250;L<=4000
2. S-BARE-w<=1250;4000<L<=6500
3. S-BARE-1250<w<=1550;L<=4000
4. S-BARE-1250< w<=1550;4000<L<=6500
```

On this I need to fetch minimum and maximum values. I am trying to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to achieve this. I am using the following regex with match parameter i & x.
I am using 4 regex strings. `\d{4}(?=<W)` to find minm width, `(?<=W<=)\d{4}` to find maxm width, `\d{4}(?=<L)` to find minm length and `(?<=L<=)\d{4}` to find maxm length. Combined regex is as follows.

```
\d{4}(?=<W)|(?<=W<=)\d{4}|\d{4}(?=<L)|(?<=L<=)\d{4}
```

But the above regex returns null for all 4 parameters ie minm_width, maxm_width, minm_length, maxm_length.

These above regex gives correct values when tried on [RegEx Simulator](https://regex101.com/r/1ZKakp/1).
But when i try the regex on oracle with `REGEXP_SUBSTR` it returns `NULL`.
Oracle statement is as follows.

```
WITH TEST_DATA AS
     (SELECT 'S-BARE-w<=1250;L<=4000' TXT_REMARKS FROM DUAL
      UNION SELECT 'S-BARE-w<=1250;4000<L<=6500' TXT_REMARKS FROM DUAL
      UNION SELECT 'S-BARE-1250<w<=1550;L<=4000' TXT_REMARKS FROM DUAL
      UNION SELECT 'S-BARE-1250<w<=1550;4000<L<=6500' TXT_REMARKS FROM DUAL)
SELECT TXT_REMARKS,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (TXT_REMARKS, '\d{4}(?=<W)', 1, 1, 'i') WIDTH_MIN,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (TXT_REMARKS, '(?<=W<=)\d{4}', 1, 1, 'i') WIDTH_MAX,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (TXT_REMARKS, '\d{4}(?=<L)', 1, 1, 'i') LENGTH_MIN,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (TXT_REMARKS, '(?<=L<=)\d{4}', 1, 1, 'i') LENGTH_MAX
  FROM TEST_DATA;
```

Any help is appreciated in resolving this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regular expressions should give your desired result:

```
WITH TEST_DATA AS
     (SELECT 'S-BARE-w<=1250;L<=4000' TXT_REMARKS FROM DUAL
      UNION SELECT 'S-BARE-w<=1250;4000<L<=6500' TXT_REMARKS FROM DUAL
      UNION SELECT 'S-BARE-1250<w<=1550;L<=4000' TXT_REMARKS FROM DUAL
      UNION SELECT 'S-BARE-1250<w<=1550;4000<L<=6500' TXT_REMARKS FROM DUAL)
SELECT TXT_REMARKS,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (TXT_REMARKS, '(\d+)<=?W', 1, 1, 'i',1) WIDTH_MIN,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (TXT_REMARKS, 'W<=?(\d+)', 1, 1, 'i',1) WIDTH_MAX,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (TXT_REMARKS, '(\d+)<=?L', 1, 1, 'i',1) LENGTH_MIN,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (TXT_REMARKS, 'L<=?(\d+)', 1, 1, 'i',1) LENGTH_MAX
  FROM TEST_DATA;
```

You can just use paranthesis to mark the parts you want to get and then refere to them with the 6. parameter of `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.

Marked the equal sign as optional for all expressions as the borders might or might not be strict.

Comment: Thanks  a lot man.. that solved it. Got another query though. How come the same worked in the simulator but not in oracle?

Comment: Oracle's regex engine does not support look-aheads or look-behinds :-/